# Does Lt. Ro speak of Tuvok in TNG episode Preemptive Strike?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

In [Preemptive Strike](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Preemptive_Strike_%28episode%29) Lt. Ro talks of one of her instructors who held the rank of Lt. Commander who left Starfleet to join the Maquis.

> RO: I've heard a lot about the Maquis. *[beat]* One of my instructors in Tactical Training... a Lieutenant Commander in Starfleet -- a man I admired and respected... was sympathetic to them. He resigned and left to join them.

That seems to fit Tuvok's record at the beginning of Voyager when he is working undercover on Chakotay's ship. Was she referring to Tuvok?

Comment: Its not answer worthy, but Tuvok was only a lieutenant (sans commander) at the time he infiltrated the mauqis. He was promoted to Lt. Cmdr. in season 4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No, Tuvok did not train at the Advanced Tactical Command school during that time. He had just left Starfleet Academy after 16 years in 2365. So it was unlikely. Ro Laren would have trained with Tuvok at the Academy but his rank at the time was still Ensign.**

> Ro Laren entered Starfleet Academy in 2358 and graduated with the class of 2362. (TNG: "Conundrum", "The Next Phase") [- Memory Alpha > Ro Laren](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ro_Laren#Academy_and_early_career)

Data on Tuvok

> Recognizing that there was much he could learn from other races such as humans, Tuvok entered Starfleet again in 2349 and served as an ensign on the USS Wyoming. (VOY: "Flashback") Tuvok was an instructor at Starfleet Academy for sixteen years, a role he resumed aboard Voyager in order to instruct Maquis crewmen in Starfleet protocols. (VOY: "Learning Curve") He also served as instructor to Icheb in his pursuits to join Starfleet. [- Memory Alpha - Tuvok](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tuvok#Return_to_Starfleet)

The other problem with this question was Ro Laren was assigned to Advanced Tactical Command School in 2369-2370 before returning to Enterprise. Chakotay was supposedly resigned from Starfleet by 2368, so how could she have ever met him in the first place?

Comment: That was a rather large edit you made.  But thank you, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 13):

No.  [According to Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Preemptive_Strike_%28episode%29#Continuity), she actually meant Chakotay:

> The lieutenant commander whom Ro Laren refers to as her instructor at Starfleet Advanced Tactical Training in 2369/2370 who joined the Maquis was intended by the producers as a reference to Chakotay of *Star Trek: Voyager* (*Star Trek: The Next Generation Companion*). This suggestion is included in Ro's biography at StarTrek.com. That intention was contradicted in VOY: "In the Flesh", where Chakotay stated that he resigned his commission on March 3, 2368.